# How to set Zingchart line border?

Tags: zingchart

Is it possible to draw a line with a border in zingchart?

I have a

```
"type" : "line",
"values"     : [something],
"line-color": "#somecolor",
```

but adding `"border-color" : "#something"` and `"border-width" : 3px` doesn't do it.

I've tried the documentation, but I haven't found anything related, except for bar series types.

edit: Forgot to say, I'm in a mixed type chart (bars + lines), I can set borders to "bar" type series, but not "line" type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZingChart's drawing engine mimics a lot of how SVG is drawn, therefore lines do not have borders inherently. However in true SVG fashion, we have a property called `top-state` that allows the user to replicate a shape to be placed right on top of the existing shape.

To emulate a border around the line, we can make the size of the top-state line-width a little thinner than the plot line-width.

Don't hesitate to reach out if you need any further assistance -- I'm a part of the ZingChart team

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "mixed", 
 series : [
  {
    type : 'bar',
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85]
  },
  {
    type : 'line',
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85],
   lineWidth : "6px",
   topState : {
     lineWidth : "2px",
     lineColor : "pink"
   }
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```